# No complexity information available for scipys linprog solvers?

Tags: optimization, scipy, time-complexity, space-complexity, scipy-optimize

Does someone know that complexitys scipys linprog solvers have? Unfortunately there's no worst-case best-case complexity in the documentation.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-interior-point.html#optimize-linprog-interior-point

Comment: The same as all the others. (Theoretical) Algorithmic complexity of LP-Solvers is nothing any OR-practitioner cares about. Simplex-based solvers have exponential worst-case (pivoting, cycling, ...), but those cases do (usually) not appear in reality. (Network-Simplex is a specialized version which can be proven to be poylomial). Interior-point solvers have polynomial worst-case. But again: nobody cares about this as it just doesn't help.

Comment: aren't there any differences in between different implementations? Especially the interioir point method should have a best case complexity which depends on the type of implementaion right?  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-interior-point.html#optimize-linprog-interior-point refers to different IP algorithms.... so I'm not sure which complexity I should apply

Comment: Yes, they differ, but you asked about *worst-case* complexity. Best-case complexity is as useless as worst-case complexity. You are interested in how those perform empirically for your use-case. This can only be evaluated empirically and theory cannot capture it (too dynamic -> sparsity-structure of instance; heuristic luck, ...). Even in continuous-cases, those solvers (less scipy's which are on the lower end of complexity; imho only simplex-based HIGHS is within the scope of state-of-the-art irt. open-source) are a bag of tricks making prediction hard. Measuring is better than guessing.

Comment: For people without much experience with different solvers, the benchmarks of Hans Mittelmann should be a primary step: [Simplex LP](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpsimp.html), [IPM LP](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpbar.html). Those provide *some* information and you might start from there. What is easily seen: 1) Commercials beat non-commercials (even worse in discrete-optimization) 2) Only one of scipy's solvers is considered *good enough* (sounds harsh; but this is really a special field!) to be benchmarked there (well; that's my point of view / interpretation; there is some truth in it though).

Comment: I agree with Sascha: these complexity measures tell you very little about how fast you can solve a particular LP model and which solver to use.  Also, note that the Scipy solvers have a matrix-based interface.  Sometimes suited for very structured models, but for most models this is very awkward.